# How do I make my server pingable?

Tags: ubuntu-9.04

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu 9.04. I have sites running fine on the server and are accessible from anywhere. However, pinging the server's IP address always results in timeouts.

I did some Googling and saw information that said to basically put `0` in the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`. I checked and that was already the case (I ran the command [on here](http://www.linuxbuddies.com/2009/01/20/enable-disable-ping-requests-in-linux/) just to make sure).

But the server is still not pingable. Is there something else that could be the problem?

PS. I have seen some places mention firewalls. I don't know if the server has a firewall installed (I haven't installed anything myself but the server came pre-built with everything). How would I find out if there is a firewall running? And can the server be pingable but keep the firewall running?

Comment: Can you ping the server from itself ? Are you running a firewall on the server?

Comment: Add the output of `iptables -nL` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you would be running iptables as a firewall. Type iptables -L as root to see if there is a rule (or the lack thereof) for ICMP requests. If there are rules, save all using iptables-save, add an additional one for your ICMPs (for example -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT) and reload the entire batch with iptables-restore.

Comment: If he doesn't know to check iptables, he's not going to know that iptables-save writes to stdout, and will need to save that to a file, to be read in with iptables-restore.

Comment: If you run a dedicated server and host several sites, I assume you are able to redirect the output of a program to a file (and possibly read a man page). Besides, he has already another question on how to save the iptables rules running.

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to server management, but I'm fairly clued up on Linux and command line usage :)

Comment: Thanks, it works now. One more question regarding save/restore: is this a good way to reorder the rules? For example, first running `iptables-save > iptables.bak`, editing that file, then running `iptables-restore < iptables.bak` ??