# Understanding/optimizing iptables output

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-9.04

Below is the result of `iptables-save` from a Ubuntu Linux server. My question is, is there anything wrong or sub-optimal about it?

For example I believe the rules are processed in order, so should the rules for ports 80 and 3306 (www/mysql) be moved to the top?

Also, what do the rules after the DROP do? They seem similar to rules further above.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.1.1 on Sun Feb 13 16:11:59 2011
*filter
:INPUT DROP [1:52]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [496336:22258327]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 69 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j DROP 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb 13 16:11:59 2011
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably move the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED ... ACCEPT` rule on the INPUT chain to the very top of that chain. Unless most of your connections are extremely short-lived, I'd wager that the vast majority of incoming packets are going to be part of a connection and should be ACCEPTed by that rule.

To get a better feel for where packets are landing in your ruleset, you can run this:

```
iptables -t filter -L -n -v
```

and pay particular attention to the packet and byte counts. You will probably notice that the rule I mentioned above has claimed the most packets by a rather large margin. If any other rules have matched a significant number of packets, you could optimize your ruleset by moving them up ahead of less "popular" rules.

Finally, I notice that your OUTPUT chain has ACCEPT policy. That makes the ACCEPT rules on the OUTPUT chain redundant, and they should be removed. Similarly, since your INPUT chain policy is DROP, the final DROP rule on the INPUT chain is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. So are you saying that the last 3 rules (i.e. the 3 lines before `COMMIT`) can be removed?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: You're welcome. And yes.

Comment: One final question (I hope!) - the rules on ports 3306 show 0 packets/bytes. Is this normal? Is it because there are no connections coming from outside (i.e. Apache communicates with MySQL locally).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Since all communications with MySQL are happening on localhost, all such traffic will be going through the loopback adapter, `lo`. You have a rule high up on the INPUT chain that accepts all connections through `lo`, and that includes all your MySQL connections. So yes, in your case, you are seeing exactly what I would expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

In general arranging the rules so that you exit the firewall quickly is a good thing. If most of the traffic is to ports 80 and 3306 then they should as you suggest be higher up the list for the INPUT table.

Iptables works on tables. You have 3, INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT. The DROP command is in the INPUT table. The rules after the DROP are for the OUTPUT chain so they will be processed for outgoing packets only. They could be removed as the policy on the OUTPUT table is to ACCEPT and they are ACCEPT rules.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT` not divided into NEW / REL, EST as others?
2. Lots of `--state NEW` is redundant, why making CPU decides whether it was `NEW` each time(?). You'd better create additional chain 'INPUT.NEW', and use single `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -j INPUT.NEW` to pipe packets into it.
3. INPUT.NEW then can be populated with port comparisons. The number of lines there can be reduced if you'd use `-m multiport`.
4. Accepting all ICMP's is insecure since it means not only echo-requests. Select only those ICMPs you're okay to have allowed (this can be as a few as just echo-requests). And remember that legitimate other protos (TCP for e. g.) specific ICMPs would be handled with `RELATED` anyway.
5. There's little sense (if any) allowing OUTPUT to be only `NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED`. Permit it w/o sub-dividing.

Comment: Re point 4 - I added ICMP because of the answer [on this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/234802/how-do-i-make-my-server-pingable/234805#234805). The server wasn't pingable before so `RELATED` wasn't handling it.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, RELATED wouldn't do that (and I didn't say  contrary), you're horribly mistaken both in understanding of mine words and ICMP. Read at least this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

Looks good.  I would drop the accept on port 20 as it should be handled as a related packet to an FTP connection.  I usually put port 123 as the first check to minimize latency for NTP.

For the OUTPUT chain only DROP or REJECT rules would make sense.  The existing output rules don't do anything but duplicate the policy.

You may want to look at your counters and adjust the ordering of rules accordingly.

Consider using different chains for new connections on each interface.

Consider logging non-accepted packets.

Using a tool like [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) to build the firewall might make it easier to get everything in place.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using one explicit rule per protocol/port combination, I'd strongly suggest using **`ipset`**.

Make 2 sets, one each for TCP and UDP:

```
ipset -N Allowed_TCP_Ports portmap --from 0 --to 65535
ipset -N Allowed_UDP_Ports portmap --from 0 --to 65535
```

Populate each set:

```
for p in $TCP_PORTS; do ipset -A Allowed_TCP_Ports; done
for p in $UDP_PORTS; do ipset -A Allowed_UDP_Ports; done
```

You can then simplify your port-related rules into just 2 rules:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m set --match-set Allowed_TCP_Ports dst -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m set --match-set Allowed_UDP_Ports dst -j ACCEPT
```

*Note: I'm removing* `-m state --state NEW` *matches. I mean, what for? After the* `-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` *rule, **all** packets are either NEW or INVALID.*

*Note 2: Ubuntu's `ipset` package is bollixed; you must download and install from source. I've explained how in my blog. You can read it here: http://pepoluan.posterous.com/powertip-howto-install-ipset-on-ubuntu .*